# Pick Image from CSS instead of HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a tricky question. Might funny to some people here.

I am trying to overcome html img and use image via css background property.

So, Code is simple:

```
<a id="logo" href="/"><img src="/logo1.png"></a>
```

CSS

```
position: relative;
height: 85px;
width: 200px;
background: url(/logo2.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 200px 200px;
```

So, I want logo1 from html removed and css image logo2 overtake logo1.

NOTE: No extra divs and classes, Only with that html markup!

Tried everything but i think this is impossible?

Comment: `a` has `display:inline` per default, and therefor `width` and `height` don’t have any effect. Add `display:inline-block`.

Comment: display: table-cell is also a good option!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the img with `display: none` and use `display: block/inline-block/table-cell` to get your height and width.

In this example the red `<img>` is being removed and replaced with the yellow CSS background image.

[Example!](http://jsbin.com/qusem/1/edit)

HTML

```
<a id="logo" href="/"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200/FF0000"></a>
```

CSS

```
a { 
   position: relative;
   height: 85px;
   width: 200px;
   background: url(http://www.placehold.it/200/FFFF00) no-repeat;
   background-size: 200px 200px;
   display: block;
}
a img {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the img tag and replace it with the background image. Use z-index and remove position:relative; from the link and apply it to the img instead. Add display:block; to the link and give it fixed dimensions.

**HTML**

```
<h2>Your actual code:</h2>
<a id="logo2" href="/"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" /></a>
<br> 
<h2>You want to hide the img tag and replace it with the background image. Use z-index and replace position:relative; and apply it to the img instead.</h2>
<a id="logo" href="/"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" /></a>
```

**CSS**

```
    #logo, #logo2{
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        display:block;
        background: url(http://www.placehold.it/100x100) no-repeat;
        background-size: 200px 100px;
        z-index:2;
    }
    #logo img{
        z-index:-1;position:relative;
    }
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/stkrj9eq/

If you want to hide the img, you can use several techniques, also using opacity, visibility:hidden, display:none; etc. Depends what you are trying to achieve.